# Transitive `require`s don't work `--with-native-compilation`?

Tags: require, provide, native-comp

Consider:

```
;;; a.el
(defun a () nil)
(provide 'a)
```

```
;;; b.el
(require 'a)
(defun b () nil)
(provide 'b)
```

In traditional Emacs this byte compiles fine:

```
;;; use.el
(require 'b)
(a) ;This is automatically available "transitively" (without native-comp)
(b)
```

But `--with-native-comp` complains that `a` is unknown; transitive `require`s are insufficient. Instead you must directly require everything, e.g.:

```
;;; use.el
(require 'a) ;NEW
(require 'b)
(a)
(b)
```

Alternatively I suppose `b.el` could `(provide 'b)` as well as `(provide 'a)`?

---

Presumably this is because each native compilation is isolated and inherits no state/environment from previous compilations?

Although this isn't necessarily a bad change (I can see the argument for it being an improvement) it's a significant change.

In searching (so far, maybe I've missed something) I haven't seen an explanation in quite these terms. For example: "**Tip**: To work with native compilation, you cannot rely on a `require` automatically providing features its has `require`d. Either add direct `require`s, or, have the required file use multiple `provide`s to supply the expected features.

1. Is my understanding of the situation correct?
2. Is my "**Tip**" correct?

Comment: Consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Are you using a current build?  `--with-nativecomp` was renamed to `--with-native-compilation` six months ago.  (You've written something in the middle, so it's hard to tell.)  In either case, this is pre-release functionality, so I agree with Drew that you should report a bug, or otherwise ask on the mailing list.

Comment: Thanks Drew and @phils for the suggestions how to follow up. This arose via https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode/pull/596 and I don't have all the details  first-hand, Either I'll equip myself with those to follow up, or, ask the original reporter to do so.

Comment: It took me awhile to get a `--with-native-compilation` build; using it I [can't repro with a simplified recipe](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode/pull/596#issuecomment-1049930002).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this turned out to be just a bleeding edge problem:

- The original report came from someone who built from source about 10 days ago.
- By the time I tried myself a couple days ago --- and they tried again today, to confirm --- the problem no longer occurs.

Glancing at the commits in that time range, I have no idea which one was the fix. My W.A.G. is one of the commits making changes around `current-load-list` and `load-history`; maybe that could cause the native compiler not to know about already, transitively loaded functions??

So I'm posting that as a self-answer, but definitely not marking it as accepted. Maybe someone will post a definitive answer and salvage some value from my question. Otherwise, I apologize if this was a distraction.

---

As a TL;DR: Native compilation is **not** intended to change the semantics of transitive `require`s. If you've built Emacs from source `--with-native-compilation` and see errors like this, try rebuilding from source again. If you still see errors like this, report them.